# Wrong selection in ios 7 with same code

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios7

I am Using This code to select my default index title for table in my drop down.
 When i run this code on **ios 6** it enters in the **else** part and when i run it on **ios 7** it enters in the **if** part **whereas it should** enter in the **else** part.
Please help me on this.

```
-(void)setSelectedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)selectedIndexPath
{

_selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath;
if (_selectedIndexPath.row == NSNotFound) {
    [self.selectedValueLabel setText:self.title];
}
else{
    [self.selectedValueLabel setText:[self.dataSource dropDown:self   optionTitleForRowAtIndexPath:_selectedIndexPath]];
}

}
```

Comment: Need more code to help you... we can't guess like it

Answer (score 0):

There are few changes in iOS 7 where `nil` is being used instead of a sentinel value. Set a break point and check if the indexPath is `nil` for some reason. If it is, `[nil row]` would return 0 and not `NSNotFound`.